# Подключение скрипта в wordpress для отображения вкладок

Tags: html, css, wordpress

подскажите как добавить скрипт для работы вкладок. Нашел пример (ниже). Из него css кусок вставил в custom-style.css, html-вставил прямо на страницу через добавить страницу, и скрипт туда же, но он не отрабатывает.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    float: bottom;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
     
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color:#f7b074;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;

}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">Директор</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Заместитель директора по организационно-инновационной деятельности</button>
 
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>



<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас там откровенно говоря бред на странице - уберите эту хрень, я скопировал группы тегов что вам нужно удалить

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

</style>
</head>
<body>
```

вот эта часть там не нужна.

все что касается кастомных css стилей ( то что в тегах `<style> </style>` ) вы можете вставить либо в файл style.css ( его можно найти "Внешний вид -> "Редактор тем" -> в сайдбаре выбрать файл стилей и вставить в него код) либо "Внешний вид" -> "Настроить" -> выбрать "Дополнительные стили" и вставить свой код css в него.

Далее. откройте ваш файл footer.php ( его можно найти "Внешний вид -> "Редактор тем" -> в сайдбаре выбрать файл footer.php и вставить в него код)

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Должно сработать, но если что обращайтесь

Comment: в какое место footer.php его вставить, пробовал рандомно в разные места файла, не работает ?